# More than one row error when populating a table

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have create a table using *create table* and with these column:

```
create table myschema.mytable(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY, 
    row_num integer, 
    col_num integer, 
    pix_centroid geometry, 
    pix_val double precision
)
```

When I am trying to populate it:

```
insert into pixelbased (id, row_num, col_num, pix_centroid, pix_val)
values (
    DEFAULT, 
    (select((ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast, 1)).x)  from mytable where rid=3),  
    (select((ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast, 1)).x)  from mytable where rid=3), 
    (select(ST_Centroid((ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast, 1)).geom)) from rwanda8 where rid=3),
    (select(ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast, 1)).val from mytable where rid=3)
)
```

I am encountered with the following error:

**ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression.**

I know that since I have more than one row for every column it does make sense to have such an error. But I really need to have all the columns calculated as mentioned. Anyone knows what should I do?
In fact I want to insert the result the following query in the table:

```
select 
    (ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast, 1)).val as geomval1, 
    (ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast, 1)).x as X, 
    (ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast, 1)).y as Y, 
    (ST_Centroid((ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast, 1)).geom)) as geom 
from rwanda8 
where rid=3
```

Anyone knows what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `select` query in instead of the `values`

```
insert into pixelbased (row_num, col_num, pix_centroid, pix_val)
select
    (ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast, 1)).val as geomval1,
    (ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast, 1)).x as X,
    (ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast, 1)).y as Y,
    (ST_Centroid((ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast, 1)).geom)) as geom
from rwanda8 where rid=3
```

Do not insert the id as it is a serial and will generate itself.

Comment: Thank you Clodoaldo. It is working for me. If I want to generalize the query to include all the rid values what should do? I want to have separate columns for `(ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast, 1)).val as geomval1` for every rid with different names. the number of columns are more 1000 and I can't do it manually.

Comment: @f.ashouri If you have more than 1,000 columns then you are doing it wrong. Create another question and explain your data asking to have it normalized.

Comment: Sorry I have more than 1000 ROWS and every one has specific rid. I think it is clear now. I want to have separate _geomval_ column for every rid.

Comment: @f.ashouri Then you want a crosstab/pivot. Open another question.

Comment: I just asked another question. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

One of your subqueries returns more than 1 row. So use `LIMIT 0,1` or something to get only one single value per subquery.

If you need more than 1 value per column, you should review your insert algorithm and use a cursor for instance.

Comment: actually all of my columns return more than one row. I want to have the query result(I just edited and added the query in the question) in a table. Could you help me more?